# Groupby keep other columns when using max()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want keep other columns when using groupby().max(). I am working with Pandas on a DataFrame with 26'000 rows and 28 columns. Currently I use this code to groupby:

```
df1.open_interest.groupby(df1.index).max()
```

with the output being:

| date | open_interest |
| --- | --- |
| 2001-11-02 | 846 |
| 2001-11-02 | 299 |

I would like to have something like this (identifier and strike are columns in df1):

| date | open_interst | identifier | strike |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001-11-02 | 846 | SMIKA | 7000 |
| 2001-11-02 | 299 | SMIKB | 8000 |

Comment: `identifier` and `strike` should be grouped too? Like, get the first element from the group?

Comment: `df1.loc[df1.groupby(df1.index)['open_interest'].idxmax()]`

Comment: essentially it should give the corresponding identifier and strike to the open_interest

Comment: df1.loc[df1.groupby(df1.index)['open_interest'].idxmax()]  does not work, the number of rows in the DataFrame is not reduced

Comment: Can you post more of your original dataframe, as well as the output desired?